# MySQLDump with last 24 Hours of data

Tags: mysql

I am having one table where data gets every 15 min interval of timestamp  like

```
2014-02-01 23:00:00
2014-02-01 23:15:00
2014-02-01 23:30:00
2014-02-01 23:45:00
2014-02-02 00:00:00
```

Now i want to dump this table data for last 24 hours. I am using MySQLDump to create dump file which will have following condition in it with where clause

```
-- WHERE:  DATE_FORMAT(emdt,'%d-%m-%Y')= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Now even with this condition i want to put one more logic is the data which get recorded at 2014-02-02 00:00:00' should also come under last 24 hours data but when it compared the data it is not picking up this data. Hence it is affecting last day billing.

So if i ran it next day same dump file it should only pickup records from 2014-02-02 00:15:00' and so on.

Please help me to put here right extraction login.

TIA,
Regards,
Nirav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
WHERE emdt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank you so Much Barmar... for your swift response really appreciate.